# SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server in python 2.4

Tags: python, linux, smtp, vps, python-2.4

This is my normal code in my VPS hosting which provide python 2.4

```
def mail(receiver,Message):
    import smtplib
    try:
        s=smtplib.SMTP()
        s.connect("smtp.gmail.com",465)
        s.login("email@gmail.com", "password")
        s.sendmail("email@gmail.com", receiver, Message)
    except Exception,R:
            return R
```

but unfortunately return this message! :
`SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.`

in my computer which i've install python 2.7 i found the solution and it's work very good  here is this code  :

```
def mail(T,M):
    import smtplib
    try:
        s=smtplib.SMTP_SSL()
        s.connect("smtp.gmail.com",465)
        s.login("xxxxx@gmail.com","your_password")
        s.sendmail("xxxxx@gmail.com", T, M)
    except Exception,R:
            print R
```

But in the VPS which installed python 2.4 doesn't have SMTP_SSL() and return this message `'module' object has no attribute 'SMTP_SSL'`

Also i've tried to upgrade my python in VPS but what happened is Damage the whole python that mean python not work at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Guys thanks i've found the solution and this is the solution =)

```
def mail(receiver,Message):
    import smtplib
    try:
        s=smtplib.SMTP()
        s.connect("smtp.gmail.com",465)
        s.ehlo()
        s.starttls()
        s.ehlo()
        s.login("email@gmail.com", "password")
        s.sendmail("email@gmail.com", receiver, Message)
    except Exception,R:
            return R
```

Comment: You can't run ``ehlo`` or ``starttls`` before ``connection``. Besides not making any sense, it raises an exception (``SMTPServerDisconnected``).

Comment: You don't need to make the first s.ehlo() call. s.starttls() will call it for you. I confirmed this in 2.7, the 2.4 docs sound like it behaves the same way in that version.

Comment: It might be worth explicitly saying that it's the double ehlo() that appears to make this work..

Answer (score 0):

Is `SMTP.starttls()` available? You can also do e.g.:

```
def mail(receiver,Message):
    import smtplib
    try:
        s=smtplib.SMTP()
        s.connect("smtp.gmail.com",587)
        s.starttls()
        s.login("email@gmail.com", "password")
        s.sendmail("email@gmail.com", receiver, Message)
    except Exception,R:
            return R
```

Comment: exact result ^_^ `SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server`