# Python smtplib login error smtplib.SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am trying to connect with my company's email server using smtplib in python Below is my code snippet:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.mycompany.com',25)
server.ehlo()        
server.starttls()
server.login('my_email@mycompany.com', 'my_password')
```

When I run my code I get the following error:

*smtplib.SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.*

After searching this error on google i found that my company's smtp server does not support starttls authentication so i have to remove **server.starttls()** this line from my code but when i remove this line I get following error:

*smtplib.SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.*

I have spent whole day to search these errors but didn't find any solution.

Comment: What if you do ehlo before and after tls?

Comment: What if you use smtplib.SMTPS? Port 465. You're sure you have the right port?

Comment: I have used ehlo before and after too but still getting the same error _smtplib.SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server_ 

Yes the setting are provided by our email admin so port is correct also I have tried to connect using other ports (465,587) and getting timeout on them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216127/smtp-auth-extension-not-supported-by-server-in-python-2-4 Does this help? Try connecting before doing anything.

Comment: `server = smtplib.SMTP()`
`server.connect(d_host,d_port)`

`server.ehlo()` 

`server.starttls()`

`server.ehlo()`

`server.login(d_email, d_password)`

Still No luck :(

Answer (score 9):

Probably, you don't need to login to the server. I don't have to when I connect to my corporate SMTP server. So you could try something like:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.mycompany.com',25)
server.ehlo()        
server.sendmail('my_email@mycompany.com', 'my_email@mycompany.com', msg)
```

Comment: You just saved me from creating a redundant SO question, +1 for that!
I dont know about the asker, but your solution worked for me, I too am working on corporate server and smtp.login() was the problem, and your answer solved it

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks :)

Comment: This will tend to work when you are inside a corporate network and want to use the company's outbound email server as a relay. Other relaying scenarios are basically universally blocked; you generally will not be able to connect to port 25 on public servers.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue with modifying below line of code, by adding port number with server name:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.mycompany.com:587')     
server.starttls()
server.login('my_email@mycompany.com', 'my_password')
```

Comment: That's weird if it works; the port number should be a separate argument.